# React router page rendering issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, react-router

Learning `React` right now tried to use `react-router` for page routing, but because of some reasons I always see the blank page instead of rendered component.
I'm using `webpack-dev-server` as dev server.
Looking for your help and advices

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <link href="dist/css/app.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="root"></div>

<script src="dist/js/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import  {Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory } from "react-router";

import App from './Pages/App';
import Archives from './Pages/Archives';
import Features from './Pages/Features';
import Settings from './Pages/Settings';

const app = document.getElementById('root');

// ReactDOM.render(<Layout/>, app);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={Features}/>
            <Route path='archives' component={Archives}/>
            <Route path='settings' component={Settings}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>
    , app);
```

App component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router'

export default class App extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return (
           <div>
                <h1>App</h1>
               <Link to="/archives">Archives</Link>
               <Link to="/settings">Settings</Link>
               {this.props.children}
           </div>
        );
    }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "Planner",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-react-html-attrs": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "history": "^4.6.1",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^2.4.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --content-base --inline --hot",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**UPDATED:**
Webpack config

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
    devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
    entry: "./js/app.js",
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
                    plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-decorators-legacy', 'transform-class-properties'],
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/js'),
        filename: "app.js",
        publicPath: '/dist/js/'
    },
    plugins: debug ? [] : [
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
    ],
};
```

Comment: V4 made some significant changes to their API and it no longer passes `children` in `props`

Comment: can you share webpack.config too??

Comment: @Rubbal v 4.1.1 as mentioned in `package.json`

Comment: the default text `App` is also not showing in html page `<h1>App</h1>` by this ?

Comment: @MayankShukla Yes, I don't see anything. Just a blank page instead of some text and links. Wathing on `http://localhost:8080/` . If I render component without using router it works `ReactDOM.render(<App/>, app);` But I need router

Comment: you are using `react-router v4`, that has been changed completely, use `react-router-dom`  check this: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: @MayankShukla thank you. Will try to find the solution

Comment: https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf check it out, if that helps